# How to query to get dates from the previous fiscal week of this year and the corresponding fiscal week from last year in a dynamic table in GCP?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, automation, report

So say I have a table that refreshes weekly. There's a column for fiscal week (FW). Say we are currently on fiscal week 32, and the way this query should go is that we always need the week prior so FW31 in this example. However, I not only need FW31 of this year, but FW31 of last year too. What's a way to create a dynamic query that would do that, if possible?

Example table below:

```
YEAR  |  FW  |  Dates       |  Info_1  
...   |  ... |  ...         |  ...
2019  |  30  |  09-02-2020  |  blah
2019  |  30  |  09-03-2020  |  blah
2019  |  30  |  09-04-2020  |  blah
...   |  ... |  ...         |  ...
2019  |  31  |  09-10-2020  |
...   |  ... |  ...         |  ...
2020  |  30  |  09-06-2020  |  
...   |  ... |  ...         |  ...
2020  |  31  |  09-14-2020  |  blah
2020  |  31  |  09-15-2020  |  blah
2020  |  31  |  09-16-2020  |  blah
...   |  ... |  ...         |  ...
```

So to my understanding, it wouldn't be possible to do it by date since the fiscal week of this year might not correspond with the exact same dates for the same fiscal week of last year. So I'm banking on utilizing the 'FW' column in order to pull it. However, again, this is something that I would like for the query to be able to change each week, as far as going from 31 to 32 and so on. This is within Google Cloud Platform, so I'd love to save it as view.

Answer (score 0):

Given that I don't know what you actually mean with "fiscal week", a possible solution could be the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `example_db`.`example_table` 
WHERE 
    `FW` = weekofyear(date(now())-7) AND
    `YEAR` IN (year(now()), year(now())-1);
```